# Use jquery at dynamically created element by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic-html

I have made a button like this in my main.js file :

```js
del_btn = document.createElement("button");
del_btn.className = "btn btn-light btn-sm ";
del_btn.type = "button";
del_btn.id = "delete_btn";
del_btn.innerHTML = 'X';
```

and put this in a `<tr>` which is in my index.html page. I wanted to make this alert something when the button gets clicked on. So I wrote a code that looks like this in my main.js file as well.

```js
$("#delete_btn").click(function() {
    alert("delete button clicked!!");
});
```

But nothing happens when I click on the button which id is 'button'. 
I have no idea why this doesn't work.
Does anyone know why this is not working?
Any advice would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: `$("tr").on('click', '#delete_btn', function() {
    alert("delete button clicked!!");
});` 
Use like this, this would work,
Using duplicate id is not a good practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per latest `jquery` try below

```
$(document).on('click', "#delete_btn", function() {
    alert("delete button clicked!!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are appending the delete_btn to document at right place like,

```
appendTo = document.getElementById("idToWhomeYouAppend")
appendTo.append(del_btn)
```

As you are creating del_btn button using plan js, attach the onclick in same way. e.g.

```
del_btn.onclick = function() {
    alert("delete button clicked!!");
};
```

So no need to register onclick using jquery but if you want to use jquery make sure jquery based code gets executed after del_button is getting appended in the dom.